# replace values in column of lists based on condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of lists in which I want to loop through each element of the list in all rows  and replace all numeric values with the string value. For example

```
                                          column
      [10.50.21.134,10.30.2.197,SLO-Y30-001,IVER02-Y30-001,DCT-Y30-001]
      [CHTN,WBGN,10.50.21.134,10.50.21.136,10.50.21.135]
```

I would like to loop through every element of the list and compare the values in multiple rows an replace all rows with the value that have the string

Expected output:

```
                                       column
               [CHTN,WBGN,SLO-Y30-001,IVER02-Y30-001,DCT-Y30-001]
               [CHTN,WBGN,SLO-Y30-001,IVER02-Y30-001,DCT-Y30-001]
```

I have large data set and the comparison might be among 10 rows each contain up to 30 elements in the list

What I'm able to do so far is to group by the rows, replace all digit values with nulls, but I'm stuck and I don't know how to concatenate or merge while keeping the order of the elements of the list the best way to compare each element in all rows and replace

```
   @staticmethod
   def test(df):
            df['doc']=df['nwctdoctrail'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))
            df['doc']=df['doc'].apply(lambda x : [w[:-2] for w in x])
            df['doc']=df['doc'].apply(lambda x: [w.replace(w,' ' if w[0].isdigit() else w) for w in x])



   @staticmethod
   def preprocess_df(df):
    test=df.groupby('grouping_key').apply(test())
```

The out put I'm getting :

```
                         doc

               ['','',SLO-Y30-001,IVER02-Y30-001,DCT-Y30-001]
               [CHTN,WBGN,'','','']
```

Comment: for first row how are you getting [CHTN,... ? How the  replacement is done I mean mapping?

Comment: If the list element starts with digit, then replace it with ‘ ‘